# How to make a .txt appear after clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file, button

I asked this question a minute ago and was not specific enough so let me try again.

I am trying to generate a report of inventory information that is already made and have it update from the user input into text boxes on the form and then have a button to make the .txt file of the report show to the screen and have the updated information on it.

I have the GUI created and have the button created and the .txt file is created. I just need to know how to make it where I can click the button and have the .txt file appear to the screen.

Comment: Appear on the screen how? Start notepad?

Comment: The report is already output to a notepad .txt file and I would like it to pop up to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Using System.Diagnostics;
    ... 
    String filename = "C:\\....\data.txt"; \\ File Created With Information
    Process.Start(filename); \\ Will open file with default program
```

The above code can be used to open an external program to display your text file.

As usual I recommend using try/catch since you are dealing with external I/O (files).

Answer (score 1):

You can just start the notepad process with your *.txt file as the argument and start the process can't you?

Found this link that might help you: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- Assign a [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) event to your button (in your class constructor for instance):

  ```
  button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
  ```
- In the event, start *notepad.exe* in a new process:

  ```
  void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
      startInfo.Arguments = "C:\Path\To\My\file.txt";
      Process.Start(startInfo);
  }
  ```